# Vanilla Jhispter : can't run test (SocketTimeOut Exception)

Tags: jhipster

I generated a new application with JHipster with gradle and mongoDB choice.
Gradle compiles well :

```
    c:\webs\workspace-jhipster\jpoc>gradle clean compileJava compileTestJava
:clean
:cleanResources UP-TO-DATE
:bootBuildInfo
:nodeSetup SKIPPED
:npmSetup SKIPPED
:webpackBuildDev SKIPPED
:processResources
:compileJava
:classes
:compileTestJava

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 6.704 secs
```

The problem arrives when I wish to run a single test :

```
gradle test --tests com.jpoc.service.UserServiceIntTest
```

which outputs :

```
com.jpoc.service.UserServiceIntTest > assertThatUserMustExistToResetPassword FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
                        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
                            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
                                    Caused by: de.flapdoodle.embed.process.exceptions.DistributionException
                                        Caused by: java.io.IOException
                                            Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
```

I pretty sure this is a misconfiguration problem, but I don't see which one.

I use lastest jhipster 4.2.0

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that embedded mongoDB tries to download the server part of mongoDB. As I pass through a proxy, I need to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

To setup mongoDB proxy in test suite with spring boot, I put for instance:

```
 @BeforeClass
    public static void setup_mongo() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{

        String proxyHost = "proxy.priv.atos.fr";
        String proxyPort = "3128";

        String proxy = System.getenv("http_proxy");
        System.out.println("Proxy URL : " + proxy);
        if(proxy != null){
            if(proxyHost == null && proxyPort == null){
                URL proxyurl = new URL(proxy);
               proxyHost = proxyurl.getHost();
               proxyPort = String.valueOf(proxyurl.getPort());
            }  
        }

        MongodStarter starter ;

        System.out.println("Proxy Host : " + proxyHost);
        System.out.println("Proxy Port : " + proxyPort);
        if (proxyHost != null && proxyPort != null) {
            IRuntimeConfig runtimeConfig = new RuntimeConfigBuilder().defaults(Command.MongoD)
                    .artifactStore(
                            new ArtifactStoreBuilder().defaults(Command.MongoD)
                                    .download(
                                            new DownloadConfigBuilder()
                                                    .defaultsForCommand(Command.MongoD)
                                                    .proxyFactory(
                                                            new HttpProxyFactory(
                                                                    proxyHost,
                                                                    Integer.parseInt(proxyPort)))
                                                    .build()).build()).build();
             starter = MongodStarter.getInstance(runtimeConfig);
        } else {
             starter = MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();
        }


        IMongodConfig mongodConfig = new MongodConfigBuilder()
                .version(Version.Main.PRODUCTION)
                .net(new Net(0, Network.localhostIsIPv6())).build();

        MongodExecutable mongodExecutable = null;

        mongodExecutable = starter.prepare(mongodConfig);
         mongodExecutable.start();

    }
```

Like this, it downloads the mongoDB server and try to run it. The next problem is that I don't have permissions to run this executable inside JVM.